# Objective-C binding pointer array to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, language-binding

I am trying to make a binding between an Objective-C library and C# within Xamarin. The class header that I am trying to bind is this:

```
@interface MGLPolyline : MGLMultiPoint <MGLOverlay>

+ (instancetype)polylineWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords
                              count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

What I can't figure is what to make the first parameter of the function. I have tried making the binding this:

```
Static][Export("polylineWithCoordinates:count:")]
    [Internal]
    MGLPolyLine PolyLineWithCoordinates(IntPtr coord, int count);



public partial class MGLPolyLine
{
    public static unsafe MGLPolyLine PolyLineWithCoordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords) 
    {
        unsafe
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(coords);
            IntPtr pointer = (IntPtr)handle;

            MGLPolyLine line = MGLPolyLine.PolyLineWithCoordinates(pointer,2);

            handle.Free();
            return line;
        }

    }
}
```

The code above always returns null from the MGLPolyLine.PolyLineWithCoordinates(pointer, 2) call, which leads me to believe that I'm not passing the array correctly. What is the correct way to do this binding?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've used Objective-Sharpie to see what binding it would create for me and this is what I got:

```
// +(instancetype)polygonWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords count:(NSUInteger)count;
[Static]
[Export ("polygonWithCoordinates:count:")]
unsafe MGLPolygon PolygonWithCoordinates (CLLocationCoordinate2D* coords, nuint count);
```

The problem now is I get the error "btouch: Unknown kind CoreLocationCoordinate2D* coords in method 'MGLPolygon.PolygonWithCoordinates' (B1002)

Comment: An advice, use ObjectiveSharpie, it will make your life easier as it will create the bindings for you. I have used it a lot of times and is a really good tool.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I looked into that before starting to do my bindings by hand, but was having trouble getting ObjectiveSharpie working so I started doing it manually. I've been able to most things that I need manually but this bit has tripped me up. If I can't figure it out then I probably will try getting ObjectiveSharpie working again.

Comment: Did you add the CoreLocation to the used frameworks? IOf I remember it right is in the AssemblyInformation class, gimme 5 mintes i boot up my mac and I will tell you exactly where to add it

Comment: Ok, foerget AssemblyInfo XD, you should have .linkWith.cs file, there is an assembly: LinkWith attribute, there you need to add all the frameworks used by the bindings on the Frameworks properties, something like Frameworks="AssetsLibrary CoreLocation CoreGraphics MobileCoreServices"

Comment: Hmm, I went ahead and tried that but no luck. My .linkWith.cs file looks like this,  [assembly: LinkWith ("libMapbox.a", LinkTarget.Arm64 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator64 | LinkTarget.Simulator, Frameworks = "CoreLocation", LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++ -lz -lsqlite3", ForceLoad = true)]  .  I think it has to do with it being a pointer, because it has no problem with regular CLLocationCoordinate2D parameters.

Comment: Hmmm, what's really strange is that is parsed as unsafe and as a pointer, as you know C# classes are passed by reference so them are already pointers for the bindings, try to remove the unsafe and the *

Comment: I should have clarified this better, but the Objective-C function is expecting an array. That's why it is being passed in as a pointer. Because you are correct in that if it wasn't expecting an array, then taking away unsafe and the * would make it good to go.

Comment: well, if it's an array then pass an array on the C# binding, change it to CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords

Comment: So you'd hope that you could do that, but when I initially tried that the compiler generated file MGLPolygon.g.cs has an error when it tries to convert the CLLocationCoordinate2D[] into a NSArray. "Cannot convert 'CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2d[]' expression to type 'Foundation.NSObject[]'"  If that was supported I would have been done with this a long time ago :(

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? I will look at the source of MapBox to see if we can have a workaround

Comment: A last shot, get back to what you had, remove the Internal attribute and instead of using a GCHandle use fixed(void* arrPtr = coords){ IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(arrPtr); //call the function with that pointer }

Comment: 2.1.0-pre.2. Here's a link to the commit that was in version.txt,  https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/commit/95f6a796da. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: np man, I know how frustrating sometimes is to do not be able to use a library just because a binding is not right

Comment: hmmm, ok, maybe this is your problem: if you take a look at .net Source you will see that a GCHandle *is not* an IntPtr, GCHandle has an extension ToIntPtr, that will really convert it to a pointer, so this can be the cause your initial binding did not work. if that's the case then the fixed on the previous comment should work

Comment: I tried using your latest suggestion, and it worked! Thank you so much Gusman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using GCHandle incorrectly. The working solution is:

```
   //ApiDefinition.cs
    [Static][Export ("polylineWithCoordinates:count:")][Internal]
 MGLPolyline PolylineWithCoordinates (IntPtr coords, nuint count);

// Extra.cs
public partial class MGLPolyline
{
    public static unsafe MGLPolyline PolylineWithCoordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords)
    {
        MGLPolyline line = null;

        fixed(void* arrPtr = coords)
        {

            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(arrPtr);
            line = MGLPolyline.PolylineWithCoordinates(ptr, 2);   
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```